# DataContractSerialization and the new keyword inheritance

Tags: c#, inheritance, serialization, xml-serialization, datacontractserializer

I have an issue where a XML element "Event" is being serialized twice because of the new keyword.  I want the derived type to only be serialized.

```
[DataContract(Name = "Division", Namespace = "")]
    public class ApiTeamDivision : ApiDivision
    {
        [DataMember]
        public new ApiTeamEvent Event { get; set; }
        [JsonIgnore]
        public new ApiDivisionSettings Settings { get; set; }
        [JsonIgnore]
        public new List<ApiPrice> Prices { get; set; }
        [JsonIgnore]
        public new List<ApiTeam> Teams { get; set; }
        [JsonIgnore]
        public new List<ApiAsset> Assets { get; set; }
        [JsonIgnore]
        public new List<ApiBracket> Brackets { get; set; }
    }   

<Division>
<Age>17</Age>
<Event i:nil="true"/>
<Event>
   <Address i:nil="true"/>
   <Assets i:nil="true"/>
   <Description i:nil="true"/>
   <Divisions i:nil="true"/>
</Event>
</Division>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't mark `[DataMember]` on the property `Event` in base class `ApiDivision`

```
class ApiDivision
{
    //[DataMember] => don't mark this
    public new ApiTeamEvent Event { get; set; }
}
```

For more, if you use `[DataContract]`, no need to use attribute `[JsonIgnore]`, because it is used for both format: json and Xml.

So, if you want to ignore property in serialization, just don't mark it with attribute `[DataMember]`

```
[DataContract(Name = "Division", Namespace = "")]
public class ApiTeamDivision : ApiDivision
{
    [DataMember]
    public new ApiTeamEvent Event { get; set; }

    public new ApiDivisionSettings Settings { get; set; }

    public new List<ApiPrice> Prices { get; set; }

    public new List<ApiTeam> Teams { get; set; }

    public new List<ApiAsset> Assets { get; set; }

    public new List<ApiBracket> Brackets { get; set; }
}
```

**Edit**:

Or you can use `(IsRequired=false, EmitDefaultValue=false)` to ignore if property is `null`:

```
class ApiDivision
{
    [DataMember(IsRequired=false, EmitDefaultValue=false)]
    public new ApiTeamEvent Event { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What If I use the base class else where that uses those properties during serialization.